# raising Ignore from a task doesn't acknowledge the message

Tags: python, celery

I want to implement a custom logic for aborting tasks that run a loop. The task is the following:

```py
@celery_app.task(bind=True, acks_late=True,  base=AbortableTask,name="task for groups")
def parallel_task(self, i, total):
    for idx, item in enumerate(range(i)):
        if self.is_aborted():
            print("task is aborted")
            self.update_state(state=REVOKED)
            raise Ignore()

        self.update_state(state="PROGRESS", meta={"current": idx + 1, "total": total})
        print(f"Doing parallel job for items {item}")
        time.sleep(random.randint(1, 4))
    return random.randint(1, 100)


@celery_app.task(bind=True, name="callback")
def callback_task(self, results):
    print("Excecuting callback")
    print(f"Results: {results}")
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 4))

def revoke_or_abort(res: Union[AsyncResult, AbortableAsyncResult]):
    res.revoke()
    parent = res.parent
    while parent:
        parent.revoke()
        if isinstance(parent, GroupResult):
            for child in parent.children:
                if isinstance(child, AbortableAsyncResult):
                    child.abort()

        parent = parent.parent
```

`revoke_or_abort` revokes tasks that haven't started yet, and/or tries to abort them if already started. 
Workflow is created and run like this:

```py
>>> group_tasks = group(parallel_task.s(30, 100) for i in range(2))
>>> workflow = chord(header=group_tasks, body=callback_task.s())
>>> res = workflow.apply_async()
>>> revoke_or_abort(res)
```

```sh
 celery -A my_module.celery worker -l info --concurrency=2 --prefetch-multiplier=1
```

Althoug tasks get aborted (and revoked) and also the chord's callback isn't executed I have the following side-effects:
Tasks are not updated to state `REVOKED` but they remain `ABORTED`. Also rerruning the workflow shows the tasks as if they were not acknoledged.

```py
# running again 
res = workflow.apply_async()
```

I see in celery:

```sh
[2020-06-14 10:49:03,968: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: task for groups[ff5c43a2-75a6-43c5-b700-66e8700573ec]  
[2020-06-14 10:49:03,969: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: task for groups[6be5b2d3-0b1b-4087-b946-b54b2dcb812f]  
[2020-06-14 10:49:03,974: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] task is aborted
[2020-06-14 10:49:03,974: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] task is aborted
[2020-06-14 10:49:03,976: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task task for groups[ff5c43a2-75a6-43c5-b700-66e8700573ec] ignored
[2020-06-14 10:49:03,976: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task task for groups[6be5b2d3-0b1b-4087-b946-b54b2dcb812f] ignored
```

which are the same task-ids as the first time I ran workflow. Why is that?. Can I trigger some how the revoke signal when a task is aborted, so I can "simulate" revoke functionality?

Comment: you basically want to retry a task ?

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat no I want to manually revoke it and have it send a revoked signal as it would if revoked before starting. Although I hacked may way through, If a task is aborted,  I return `None` and handle it in the `on_success` callback. When revoking a workflow, all tasks are revoked, so although all members of the header of the chord might be successfull (but aborted) the chord will be revoked and the flow will stop

Comment: Also I needed to change the revoke_or_abort code, because when reconstructing an async result from a tuple, it deson't hold informationg regarding the type of the AsyncResult (whether it was AbortableAsyncResult or plain AsyncResult)